# How can I split my javascript code into separate files?

Tags: javascript, class, dependencies, hierarchy

I'm reading the Javascript [Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) from Mozilla
And when they contrasted JS to Java , It got me thinking, Java code is easily split up with each class in his own file. after futher search , I understand that the same can be accomplished in JS with namespacing and module pattern - I messed around with it but got very confused ( especially with calling a constructor declared in File1.js into File2.js )

so here is the hierarchy:
[image: class organization]

But i just can't figure out how to properly make it works

how do i simply go from

```
//employe.js
function Employee () {
  this.name = "";
  this.dept = "general";
}

function Manager () {
  this.reports = [];
}
Manager.prototype = new Employee;

function WorkerBee () {
  this.projects = [];
}
WorkerBee.prototype = new Employee;

function SalesPerson () {
  this.dept = "sales";
  this.quota = 100;
}
SalesPerson.prototype = new WorkerBee;
```

to this :

```
 // employe.js
function Employee () {
  this.name = "";
  this.dept = "general";
}

 // Manager.js   
function Manager () {
  this.reports = [];
}
Manager.prototype = new Employee;

 // WorkerBee.js     
function WorkerBee () {
  this.projects = [];
}
WorkerBee.prototype = new Employee;

 // SalesPerson.js      
function SalesPerson () {
 this.dept = "sales";
 this.quota = 100; 
 }
SalesPerson.prototype = new WorkerBee;
```

Comment: All you have to do is include the files in the correct order.

Comment: @FelixKling: As the code only declares the constructor functions and doesn't create anything, the order that the files are included doesn't even matter.

Comment: @Guffa: It does, they are creating an instance for prototype inheritance, e.g. `Manager.prototype = new Employee;`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Oh, you are right. I stand corrected. They do need to be included in the right order.

Comment: If using modern `class`es, I solved this problem like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62142995/1599699

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should have one *global* namespacing object which every module has to access and write to. Modify your files like so:

```
// employe.js

window.myNameSpace = window.myNameSpace || { };

myNameSpace.Employee = function() {
    this.name = "";
    this.dept = "general";
};
```

and *Manager.js* could look like

```
// Manager.js

window.myNameSpace = window.myNameSpace || { };

myNameSpace.Manager = function() {
    this.reports = [];
}
myNameSpace.Manager.prototype = new myNameSpace.Employee;
```

This is of course a very simplified example. Because the order of loading files and dependencies is not child-play. There are some good librarys and patterns available, I recommend you looking at *requireJS* and *AMD* or *CommonJS* module patterns. http://requirejs.org/

Comment: this make perfect sense, thank you - I looked at requireJS but I didn't quite understood how it would help me here - I think I'm confusing between require php style and JS

Comment: I'm guessing you added `window.myNameSpace = window.myNameSpace || { };` in each file to avoid any loading errors. Is that correct?

Comment: @zachdyer I'd agree. Just check how EaseIJS does: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/src/easeljs/filters/BlurFilter.js, it does the same trick

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to do anything differently. Just include the script files and they work as if it was a single file.

Javascript doesn't have file scope. Once the code is parsed it doesn't matter where the code came from.

Comment: True - but its whether good practice nor convenient. You should mention that this only works because the *global object* is the *variable object* for itself and hence, all *var* and *function* declarations are implicitly written to it. Clobbering the global object like so is still bad karma.

Comment: @jAndy: Yes, you are right that keeping the identifiers out of the global scope is better practice, but it's not a step that is at all needed to put the code in separate files.

Comment: @Guffa I keep reading that we should avoid "polluting" the global scope is there a other reason beside not exposing a variable that we do not want to modify ?

Comment: @MimiEAM: Yes. When you use more than one script library in a page, the risk that their identifiers clash is less if they define less global identifiers.

Comment: This is not true for JS classes today.

Answer (score 5):

For small and medium projects like a website or game, the native namespacing and constructors work very well. They are a poor choice when the loading order is too complex to handle without some sort of autoloading.

index.html:

```
<script src="Employee.js"></script>
<script src="Manager.js"></script>
```

Manager.js:

```
var Manager = function() {
    var employee1 = new window.Employee(this);
    var employee2 = new window.Employee(this);
};
```

Employee.js:

```
var Employee = function(boss) {
    // work stuff here
    this.wage = 5;
};
```

Note, properties inside the employee constructor function are visible to the manager. The `new` word signals a constructor. This is also possible without a constructor by returning an object with properties instead of a function as shown above.