# Splitting a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 8000 line JS file, which I want to divide. My JS contains a single class with many methods under it. like

```
   var myClass:{
       method1:function(param1){
        //Useful code
       },
      method2:function(param1){
        //Useful code
       },
      method3:function(param1){
        //Useful code
       },
       method4:function(param1){
        //Useful code
       },
 ........
}
```

Now I want to divide this file that means am going to divide the class itself. 
Can I define few function in one file and rest in another file inside the same class. 
Some thing like the bellow mentioned code

```
File1.js:  var myClass:{
               method1:function(param1){
                //Useful code
               },
              method2:function(param1){
               //Useful code
              }
..........
          }

File2.js: 
     var myClass:{
               method3:function(param1){
                //Useful code
               },
              method4:function(param1){
               //Useful code
              }
..........
          }
```

Is there any way I can achieve this and How ?

Comment: Maybe this will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105776/how-can-i-split-my-javascript-code-into-separate-files

Comment: Have you looked at [requirejs](http://www.requirejs.org)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, you can define the class in `File1.js` like so:

```
var myClass = {
           method1:function(param1){
            //Useful code
           },
          method2:function(param1){
           //Useful code
          }
          ..........
      };
```

and then because functions are objects in JS, just extend it in `File2.js` like this:

```
 myClass.method3 = function(param1){
            //Useful code
           };
 myClass.method4 = function(param1){
           //Useful code
          };
          ..........
```

You just have to maintain the order when including the files in the browser or wherever you use them.

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested by @vanthome should work. To make it a bit more structured and perhaps make the order of the files more obvious and matter a little less, you could do it like this:

FileHeader.js

```
var myClass = {};
```

File1.js

```
myClass.method1 = function(par1) {
    // Useful code
};
myClass.method2 = function(par1) {
    // Useful code
};
```

File2.js

```
myClass.method3 = function(par1) {
    // Useful code
};
myClass.method4 = function(par1) {
    // Useful code
};
```